.NET MAUI on Android - How to check if image file exists?
I've got a bunch of images that are added to the project as:
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\stickers\myimage0.png"/>

I add them to the UI during runtime via:
#if IOS
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile($"{imageName}{imageNumber}.png"),
#else
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile($"Resources/Images/stickers/{imageName}{imageNumber}.png"),
#endif

Above works fine, however I'd like to check if the image file exists before adding them. For IOS, below works perfectly fine:
#if IOS
            if (!await FileSystem.AppPackageFileExistsAsync($"{imageName}{imageNumber}.png"))
                continue;
#endif

However, I cannot do the same check on Android, even if I give the full path.
I have also tried File.Exist with pretty much all path combinations with no luck.
How can I check on Android if a given image file exists?

If the images are added to the project at build time, it should be impossible for them to be missing at runtime

How about setting the build action to MauiAsset ?In this way ,you can refer to the image.

You already know which images are going to be in you package before build.
Anyway, Coming to reason why FileSystem.AppPackageFileExistsAsync() isn't working as you expected in Android.
For iOS, All the MauiImages will be available at NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath just like MauiAsset, BundleResource...The implementation of AppPackageFileExistsAsync check for the same.
For Android, It's bit different, Android won't expose the compiled resources like MauiImage as part of filesystem. They can only be accessed using unique resource id's.
Any files that are set build action as MauiAsset, BundleResource are considered as Assets in Android.....In this case the implementation of AppPackageFileExistsAsync will work.
You can check if image(Resources/Images/) exist in app package with something like below for android
var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
var resourceName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension($"{imageName}{imageNumber}.png");
int resourceId = context.Resources.GetIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", context.PackageName);
return resourceId != 0;

